# How to keep Android running in Kiosk Mode when calling a new application?

Tags: android, kiosk-mode

My Android app has device owner status and can run in kiosk mode by calling `startLockTask()`

What I'm trying to figure out is how to call another application from my application, and keep it in kiosk mode. Are there any flags I can set to my intent to keep this new app in the same task? Currently it won't let me call out of my application because unpinning is not allowed while in kiosk mode.

I also can't call `stopLockTask()` in this app and then `startLockTask()` in the other application because the other app won't be device owner (unless... can I have more than one device owner?)

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. Below is my method.

```
private void enableKioskMode() {

    ComponentName deviceAdmin = new ComponentName(this, AdminReceiver.class);
    DevicePolicyManager mDpm = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);

    // First of all, to access anything you must be device owner
    if (mDpm.isDeviceOwnerApp(getPackageName())) {

        // If not device admin, ask to become one
        if (!mDpm.isAdminActive(deviceAdmin) &&
                mDpm.isDeviceOwnerApp(getPackageName())) {

            Log.v(TAG, "Not device admin. Asking device owner to become one.");

            Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
            intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, deviceAdmin);
            intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION,
                    "You need to be a device admin to enable kiosk mode.");

            startActivity(intent);
        }

        // Device owner and admin : enter kiosk mode
        else {
            mDpm.setLockTaskPackages(deviceAdmin, new String[]{
                    getPackageName(), /** PUT OTHER PACKAGE NAMES HERE! */
            });
            startLockTask();
        }
    }

    // Not device owner - can't access anything
    else {
        Log.v(TAG, "Not device owner");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Not device owner", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

All you need to do is put the package names of any other apps you want to run in kiosk mode in the above `String[]` created in `mDpm.setLockTaskPackages()`. Next, make sure you call `stopLockTask()` before you send an intent to another application. Otherwise you won't be able to navigate away from this app because it's already locked.

Then all you have to do is call `startLockTask()` from any of those applications in the `String[]`. Instead of asking if you want to pin those apps, the home and recent apps buttons will disappear and they will lock right into kiosk mode. Remember to call `stopLockTask()` when you're done!